# Firefox antialising disabled, when using fixed DIV

Tags: html, css, antialiasing

I found a strange bug in Firefox. I've tested it in Chrome too, but didn't happened..

I'm using a background object. It's a div with fixed position and 1920*1050 sized. I need this, because I want my site compatible with every resolutions. Smaller resolution hide the big part of the background, but full HD users can see the whole background.

If I use absolute position for this div, my browser give me horizontal scrolling ability. I can hide it with hidden overflow, but I can't disable the scrolling ability. With fixed position the browsers doesn't "see" the whole object, and it's equal to disabled horizontal scrolling.

If anybody have any other solutions I would be very grateful for it.

The problem with this solution, is this:

[image]

You can see the difference between the two. It's the same text styling, but no anti-aliasing on fixed one. With smaller font-size it's really annoying.

Anybody met this bug in the past? How could I fix it, or any other solution for background image?

**Update**

Okay, I deleted the div, and added background for my body tag, with fixed attribute, and happens the same...
background-attachment: fixed;  < Causes the same problem

Comment: to me the rendering of the image under position fixed looks much better then the other one

Comment: hmm, maybe you have high resolution, and you cant see the rough "e" letters.

Comment: Just a remark about your 1920x1050 background... technology has already caught up with you.

Comment: Anti-aliasing uses the background color. Is one defined?

Comment: The image doesn't fit all monitors. I have a 2000+px width monitor, so your statement that it covers all HD monitors is wrong; I would at minimum support 1920x1080 background dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your background is supposed to be doing. But if you need a proportionally scaling background that fits all browser window sizes, you can use [this](http://dev.andreaseberhard.de/jquery/superbgimage/)plugin and a reasonably high resolution JPG with preload on.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any box-shadow property from the parent element. This worked for me.